# getting uptime or downtime of systemd process using systemctl?

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

like using `systemctl is-active <servicename>` gives is if service is active or failed then is it possible  to get the uptime or downtime of the systemd service all using systemctl ?

```
time systemctl status kdm|cat
* kdm.service - LSB: X display manager for KDE
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/kdm; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2017-06-21 12:03:26 CEST; 1h 42min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/kdm.service
```

is it possible to get the **1h 42min** using systemctl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using systemctl's property WatchdogTimestamp

```
 blr8-100-208-Vin:~ # systemctl show novell-nss --property WatchdogTimestamp
 WatchdogTimestamp=Tue 2020-11-24 17:30:20 IST
```

Comment: What's the source material that describes WatchdogTimestamp as the "uptime" of the service?

Comment: AFAICT this only works for services that use the watchdog facility.

Answer (score 9):

Using GNU grep with options -P and -o

```
systemctl status kdm | grep -Po ".*; \K(.*)(?= ago)"
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the timestamp of when the systemd unit last entered the "Active" phase:

```
systemctl show --property=ActiveEnterTimestamp kdm
```