# Time since the systemd service was started - Bash

Tags: bash

I want to know the time duration since a `systemd` service was started, using the `--property=ActiveEnterTimestamp` i can see the time it has started, and i would like to compare it with current time and get a value in seconds or minutes, how can i achieve this with bash

If i use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63260630/6499252) solution i am getting a string, but i cannot actually get any time object to make the decision, any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that bash doesn't work with "objects" of any sort. It has some support for arithmetic if you can transform things to numbers, but most of the time it's just passing strings to and from other commands. Generally, people asking "how can I do this with bash?" should really be asking "what standard utility program can I use to do this?"

Comment: top -b -n 1 | grep systemd. It should be a good start, then you can parse the output to get the time. It's only part of the answer, I don't have much time to do a proper and complete one. I'm not sure if it's the good answer too.

Comment: @LittlePanic404, that's measuring systemd itself, not a service it started. Also, systemd services are organized into cgroups, so there are a lot of extra OS-level facilities for cgroup-level accounting that `top` doesn't understand.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for your insight, I'm not expert at all in this domain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GNU date to convert the ActiveEnterTimestamp value to seconds-since-the-epoch, then subtract the current seconds-since-the-epoch to get the running time in seconds.

```sh
servicestartsec=$(date -d "$(systemctl show --property=ActiveEnterTimestamp your-service-here | cut -d= -f2)" +%s)
serviceelapsedsec=$(( $(date +%s) - servicestartsec))
```

Substitute "your-service-here" for your actual service name.

The first line assigns the start time in seconds by extracting the date portion of `systemctl show --property=ActiveEnterTimestamp...` (using `cut` to extract the second `=`-delimited field) and then passing it to GNU `date` and asking for output in seconds-since-the-epoch.

The second line simply subtracts that start time from the current time to get an elapsed time in seconds. Divide that as needed to get elapsed minutes, hours, etc.